# Qual a diferença entre Activity, FragmentActivity e Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Quais são as diferenças no funcionamento, desempenho etc. em herdar de cada uma das classes nos *controllers* das views (XML) no Android?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tanto a [Activity](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/components/activities.html) como o [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/components/fragments.html) são componentes que fornecem uma interface gráfica(UI), para permitir que o usuário interaja com a aplicação.
A diferença fundamental é que um Fragment necessita de uma Activity para ser apresentado.

O Fragment foi introduzido no Android 3.0 (API de nível 11) e o seu intuito principal é permitir maior flexibilidade na criação de UI adaptáveis às várias dimensões de telas existentes nos dispositivos actuais.
Ele permite centralizar o código referente a uma parte(fragmento) da UI.
Ao dividir o layout de uma Activity em fragmentos, é possível modificar a aparência da Activity, em tempo de execução, de forma simples.
Outra vantagem é o reaproveitamento do código, pois eles podem ser usados em mais de uma Activity.

Há quem use o Fragment, sem uma *view* associada, para implementar o padrão MVP.
O fragment faz de *presenter*, aproveitando a possibilidade que este tem, chamando o método [setRetainInstance(true)](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29), de não ser destruído durante a recriação da Activity(como a resultante da rotação do dispositivo), mantendo o estado da aplicação.

A [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) é um *"wrapper"* em volta de uma Activity para permitir que o Fragment possa ser utilizado em dispositivos com Android anterior à versão 3.

Comment: Esqueci desse "detalhe" que é explicar a relação/diferença entre activities e fragments. Ótima explicação. :)

Comment: @Piovezan Para quem diz que percebe pouco do assunto, a sua resposta está boa e recebeu o meu +1.

Answer (score 5):

Ia responder através de um comentário porque meu conhecimento nesse aspecto é limitado, mas ia ficar muito grande.

A diferença, se houver, é entre `Activities` e `Fragments`. De performance acredito que não haja. Quanto a funcionalidade, `Fragments`, por serem reutilizáveis, permitem interfaces mais complexas que `Activities` com código mais simples.

Até onde vai minha pouca experiência com MVP/MVC para Android, tanto `Activities` como `Fragments` requerem atenção devido aos seus ciclos de vida. No momento não consigo visualizar se o uso de `Fragments` torna mais complicada a comunicação entre os componentes, mas cogito que minimizar essa complicação seja uma das intenções de se usar MVP/MVC.

Quando às demais classes (`FragmentActivity`, `ActionBarActivity`, `AppCompatActivity`), elas existem por questão de compatibilidade com versões mais antigas do Android. [Esta resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31297546/2241463) ilustra as diferenças entre elas.

PS: Se você estiver falando de MVVM usando Data Binding, aí então que não sei nada. :)